# Proving a metric and complete metric space

Tags: real-analysis

Let $C$ denote the set of all continuous functions on $[a,b]$. Define $$d(f,g)=max\{|f(x)-g(x)|:x\in[a,b]\}$$ Prove that $d$ is a metric on $C$ and $C$ is a complete metric space under this metric. Also is there a countable collection in $C$ that is dense under this metric? (no need to prove that the collection is dense)

I'm having trouble with the triangle inequality part of the metric. Since the max difference can occur at different $x$ values, how do I prove that the max difference between $f$ and $g$ occurring at some $x$ is less than or equal to the sum of the two max differences between $f$ and $h$, $h$ and $g$ occurring two other $x$ values?

I also have trouble proving that all Cauchy sequences in $C$ converge to an element in $C$, which would prove the metric space is complete.

Comment: You should know how to show that $\max_{x} (f(x) + g(x)) \leq (\max_x f(x))+ (\max_x g(x))$. Use this to prove the triangle inequality.

Comment: I don't see how this solves my problem. The $x$ values can be different for each $d(a,b)$.

Answer (score 0):

For triangle inequality: suppose there is $x_0 : |f(x_0)-g(x_0)| > d(f,h)+d(h,g)$ for some $h$. But $|f(x_0)-g(x_0)| \le |f(x_0)-h(x_0)|+|h(x_0)-g(x_0)| \le d(f,h)+d(h,g)$.

For space completeness: let $f_n \in \{\mathbb{N} \to C\}$ be a Cauchy sequence. Define $f: f(x)=\lim_{n\to \infty}f_n(x)$, prove that it's defined for every $x$, prove it's continuous, prove that it's the limit of $f_n$.

Comment: Thank you, that was very helpful. For finding a countable collection that is dense, what should I do? I know that you can prove a set $S$ is dense by proving for every nonempty open set $U$ in $C$, $U\cap S=\emptyset$, how would I do that here? Or is there another method?

Comment: @oper $U \cap S \neq 0$, probably? Anyway, here is a hint: any continuous function is defined by its values in rational numbers (countable set). If you needed to build countable family of functions $\{r_\imath\}$ so that for $\varepsilon=1$, $\forall f \in C : |f|<{1 \over \varepsilon}, \exists \imath: d(r_\imath,f)<\varepsilon$, how would you do it? For $\varepsilon={1 \over 2}$?

Comment: back to the Cauchy sequences, how do we prove the it's defined for every $x$ if we don't know that we are in $\mathbb R$? Does a Cauchy sequence have to converge if it's not in $\mathbb R$?

Comment: @oper Nope, I assumed $C$ is $\{[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}\}$. Otherwise the sequence $f_n(x)=q_n$ where $(q_n)$ is fundamental and doesn't converge, is fundamental and doesn't converge itself.

Comment: Ok, so do we need to show that $f_n(x)$ is convergent for any $x$? Or can we just assume that since the domain is in $\mathbb R$?

Comment: @oper You need to prove three statements: (1) $f(x)$ is defined - i.e. $\forall x \in [a,b], \exists \lim_{n \to \infty}f_n(x)$; (2) $f \in C$ - i.e. $f(x)$ is continuous for all $x \in [a,b]$; (3) $f$ is a limit of $f_n$ - i.e. $\forall \varepsilon > 0, \exists n_0(\varepsilon) \in \mathbb{N} : n>n_0 \implies d(f,f_n) < \varepsilon$.

Comment: I know how to prove the 2nd and 3rd statement given that $f_n(x)$ is convergent for any $x$, but I don't know how to prove that

Comment: @oper I'd say (3) is the hardest of them. For (1), take any $x$; $|f_n(x)-f_m(x)| \le max\{|f_n(t)-f_m(t)|\}=d(f_n,f_m)$, so $f_n(x)$ is a fundamental sequence. Thus, it converges.

Comment: we have not learned the concept of fundamental sequences, is there another way to prove this?

Comment: @oper "fundamental sequence" is the same as "Cauchy sequence". It's just more familiar term for me, so I tend to use it.

Comment: Ok, and then we can use the "$\varepsilon/3$ trick to prove continuity, what about the limit part?

Comment: @oper Well, think about it on your own. The last hint: suppose inverse, i.e. that there is some $\varepsilon>0$ so that there are arbitrarily large $n : d(f,f_n)\ge \varepsilon$. Since domain of $f, f_n$ is closed set $[a,b]$, there is some value $x_0(n)$ for which $|f(x_0)-f_n(x_0)|=d(f,f_n)$ (that's important, the statement doesn't hold for open interval $(a,b)$, you may try to find a counterexample). $x_0(n)$ sounds like a sequence, and it has converging subsequence (why?). And when you think about value of $f$ at this limit, you arrive to a contradiction...

Comment: I got that part down, thank you! I don't quite understand the meaning of letting $|f|<\frac{1}{\varepsilon}$ in your construction of $\{r_\iota\}$

Comment: @oper Without this restriction, you can't easily build $\{r_\imath \}$ (basic idea is to create "lattice" with countable "width" and finite "height", then set of all graphics on this lattice is countable). Then you build a countable set of such sets ($\{\{r_\imath \}_\jmath \}$) for different $\varepsilon_\jmath \to 0$, so that each function is eventually approximated on some lattice.